# Hibernate: Does a thread block while waiting for the database to insert a batch?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to find the optimal batch size for some operations we perform in bulk (persisting collections).  If insert is going to block a thread, I think I'm going to want to make the batch size ~ the average size of the collection we are going to persist.

If that isn't the case, it might make more sense to find a smaller batch size to use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is synchronous which means that control will return to your code as soon as the operation is completed (either successfully or with an error).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the thread is going to block. If you don't want your main thread to block, you can do the updates in a separate thread.

BTW, I can not see the relation of batch-size with thead-blocking issue. The thread is going to block no matter what batch size you use.